# Android Smart App Banner doesn't scale with screen

Tags: css, smartbanner

I've created a Smart App Banner for Android using [jquery.smartbanner](http://jasny.github.io/jquery.smartbanner/). I've managed to make it work, but the problem is that the banner (which has a width of 100%) doesn't scale with the screen. So when the user opens the page it's zoomed in (because the website is not responsive) and when he zooms out, the banner (which previously had a width of 100%) now maintains the same width, so it only covers a small percentage of the page. Is there a way to fix this? The official CSS code is provided below.

Many thanks!

```
#smartbanner { position:absolute; left:0; top:-82px; border-bottom:1px solid #e8e8e8; width:100%; height:78px; font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif; background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #f4f4f4 0%,#cdcdcd 100%); background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%, #CDCDCD 100%); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F4F4 0%, #CDCDCD 100%); box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); z-index:9998; -webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased; overflow:hidden; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; }
#smartbanner, html.sb-animation {-webkit-transition: all .3s ease;}
#smartbanner .sb-container { margin: 0 auto; }
#smartbanner .sb-close { position:absolute; left:5px; top:5px; display:block; border:2px solid #fff; width:14px; height:14px; font-family:'ArialRoundedMTBold',Arial; font-size:15px; line-height:15px; text-align:center; color:#fff; background:#070707; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:none; border-radius:14px; box-shadow:0 2px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); -webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased; }
#smartbanner .sb-close:active { font-size:13px; color:#aaa; }
#smartbanner .sb-icon { position:absolute; left:30px; top:10px; display:block; width:57px; height:57px; background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); background-size:cover; border-radius:10px; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); }
#smartbanner.no-icon .sb-icon { display:none; }
#smartbanner .sb-info { position:absolute; left:98px; top:18px; width:44%; font-size:11px; line-height:1.2em; font-weight:bold; color:#6a6a6a; text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8); }
#smartbanner #smartbanner.no-icon .sb-info { left:34px; }
#smartbanner .sb-info strong { display:block; font-size:13px; color:#4d4d4d; line-height: 18px; }
#smartbanner .sb-info > span { display:block; }
#smartbanner .sb-info em { font-style:normal; text-transform:uppercase; }
#smartbanner .sb-button { position:absolute; right:20px; top:24px; border:1px solid #bfbfbf; padding: 0 10px; min-width: 10%; height:24px; font-size:14px; line-height:24px; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; color:#6a6a6a; background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #efefef 0%,#dcdcdc 100%); text-transform:uppercase; text-decoration:none; text-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.8); border-radius:3px; box-shadow:0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.6),0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.7) inset; }
#smartbanner .sb-button:active, #smartbanner .sb-button:hover { background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dcdcdc 0%,#efefef 100%); }

#smartbanner .sb-icon.gloss:after { content:''; position:absolute; left:0; top:-1px; border-top:1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.8); width:100%; height:50%; background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 100%); border-radius:10px 10px 12px 12px; }

#smartbanner.android { border-color:#212228; background: #3d3d3d url('dark_background_stripes.gif'); border-top: 5px solid #88B131; box-shadow: none; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-close { border:0; width:17px; height:17px; line-height:17px; color:#b1b1b3; background:#1c1e21; text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000; box-shadow:0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8) inset,0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3); }
#smartbanner.android .sb-close:active { color:#eee; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-info { color:#ccc; text-shadow:0 1px 2px #000; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-info strong { color:#fff; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-button { min-width: 12%; border:1px solid #DDDCDC; padding:1px; color:#d1d1d1; background: none; border-radius: 0; box-shadow: none; min-height:28px}
#smartbanner.android .sb-button span { text-align: center; display: block; padding: 0 10px; background-color: #42B6C9; background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#42B6C9),to(#39A9BB)); background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#42B6C9,#39A9BB); text-transform:none; text-shadow:none; box-shadow:none; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-button:active, #smartbanner.android .sb-button:hover { background: none; }
#smartbanner.android .sb-button:active span, #smartbanner.android .sb-button:hover span { background:#2AC7E1; }

#smartbanner.windows .sb-icon { border-radius: 0px; }
```

Comment: I'm not getting jquery.smartbanner working on my android phone despite following the README. Would you mind posting your JS? Perhaps its my device that is the problem?

Comment: @SMT I'm using the exact script I've downloaded from the website. Maybe you forgot to put `<script type="text/javascript"> $().smartbanner(); </script>` in the body of your page?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it myself! Set `#smartbanner` to `position:fixed;` and you're done :-)